# How do I select the url bar with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, monterey

On Big Sur and every previous version of macOS, I used <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the address bar in Safari. I actually do this quite frequently and on Monterey, it doesn’t work. This is frustrating me way more than it probably should. Does it work for other people? Is there any work-around? I've tried searching through the menus and I can't find anything to assign a shortcut to that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: solved! I had to turn off content blocking in screentime. No idea why this was related, but turning off content and privacy restrictions in screen time all together fixed it. I can now press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Quitting Safari (like, completely quitting it) and reopening it seems to have solved it.